# Why do logical vectors in RStudio View mode not show length?

Tags: r, rstudio

Of the basic vector types, is there any special reason why the logical does not show its length?

```r
View(list(1:10, rep(NA, 10), rep(1.0, 10), rep('x', 10)))
```

[image: View]

Comment: Maybe a bug in Rstudio? You can check the lengths with `lengths()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed a bug: thanks for filing an issue (https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/4347). This will be fixed in the next release of RStudio (v1.2).